# How can I hide the upload and new buttons from the taskbar in modern view?

Tags: modern-experience, flow, hide-elements

I wonder if you can give me a hand.

I need to hide the following controls that are marked in purple:

I'm working on a hybrid page:

Using classic view on the top and inserting the modern view of a library with a "show webpage in iframe web part" option.

How can I hide this mentioned controls? 
I am not allowed to use the spfx framework.

I have to display the modern view inserted in the custom html page created in sharepoint designer in the way it is.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kaiserin, you can assign Read or view permission for those users, so that new, upload option will get disappear from the view